# Parsing movie transcript with BeautifulSoup - How to ignore tags nested within text?

Tags: beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to parse a movie transcript that looks like this:

```
<b>A</b>: Look!
<br/>
<b>B</b>: (<i>whispers</i>) Shhh. Be quiet.
<br/>
<b>A</b>: (<i>lowering voice</i>) Sorry.
<br/>
```

I tried to pull all of character A's dialogue using this code:

```
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

A_entire_dialogue = []

A_lines = soup.find_all('b', string='A')
for line in A_lines:
    dialogue = line.nextSibling
    A_entire_dialogue.append(dialogue)

# Code above returns [': Look!', ': (']
```

I want to pull the character directions within the i tags along with the rest of the dialogue text. How can I edit the code, so that the result is [': Look!', ': (lowering voice) Sorry.']?

EDIT: Thank you for your help! All of your answers work for the snippet of HTML provided, but I ended up writing my own code that works better for parsing the entire transcript:

```
A_entire_dialogue = []

for i in soup.find_all('b', string='A'):
    for sib in i.next_siblings:
        if sib.name == None: 
            A_entire_dialogue.append(sib)
        elif sib.name == 'i':
            A_entire_dialogue.append(sib.get_text())
        elif sib.name == 'br':
            break
        else:
            print("Note: new tag not previously encountered.")
            break
```

Comment: I don’t know BeautifulSoup, but shouldn’t you keep pulling siblings until you reach the <br/> element instead of just taking the first sibling? Try drawing this HTML as a tree.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod thank you! I'm new to coding and didn't realize that was an option, but I figured it out thanks to your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = """
<b>A</b>: Look!
<br/>
<b>B</b>: (<i>whispers</i>) Shhh. Be quiet.
<br/>
<b>A</b>: (<i>lowering voice</i>) Sorry.
<br/>
"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

A_entire_dialogue = []

for text in soup.text.split("\n"):
    if text and text.startswith("A"):
        A_entire_dialogue.append(text[1:])

print(A_entire_dialogue)
```

Output:

```
[': Look!', ': (lowering voice) Sorry.']
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc
html = '''
<b>A</b>: Look!
<br/>
<b>B</b>: (<i>whispers</i>) Shhh. Be quiet.
<br/>
<b>A</b>: (<i>lowering voice</i>) Sorry.
<br/>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
A_lines = doc.getElementsByReg("A",tag="b").nextText(end="<br />")
print (A_lines)
```

Result:

```
[': Look!', ': (lowering voice) Sorry.']
```